# Where joomfish store and get translation categories?

Tags: joomla, translation, joomfish

I use joomla 2.5, joomfish 2.5.1.

I have a category B is transation of category A. How I detemine that when I view in database? What table store it? What field I must to find?

I see 'categories', 'assets', 'jf_content', 'jf_translationmap' table but I can't find the way.

Sorry my english!.

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel in SEO configuration panel uncheck add suffix to URL